# Сериализация и сохранение словаря в файл и последующее чтение

Tags: c#, сериализация

Здравствуйте! Появилась задача сохранять словарь, где значениями являются объекты и затем читать его из файла. Подскажите как лучше это реализовать? Почитал кучу гайдов как сериализуют объекты, но там везде используются листы, а словарь найти не могу. 
Вот структура объекта и сам словарь:

```
struct show
{
    int[] place;
    string moviename;
}

public Dictionary<DateTimeOffset, show> dict = new Dictionary<DateTimeOffset, show>();
```

Вот этот дикт мне и нужно сохранить и затем прочитать обратно в такой же словарь из файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть возможность тянуть за собой внешнюю библиотеку, порекомендую Json.net
Вот из её документации

string json = @"{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":""value2""}";

Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

Console.WriteLine(values.Count);

Console.WriteLine(values["key1"]);

Comment: Уже реализовал, как написано тут http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file. Но спасибо! Про Json я вообще забыл, хотя постоянно пользуюсь этой библиотекой.